# Use Gdal2tiles to generate 512px tiles

Tags: gdal, generate-tiles, gdal2tiles

I'm a newbie in gdal2tiles & python but I would like to modify gdal2tiles to create 512px tiles for retina display (screen).

Can someone suggest how I can do this?

Comment: There seems to be "tileSize=256" in many places of the script. Try to use 512 instead and see what it breaks. The current code is http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal2tiles.py

Comment: Thank for answer.I tried that already.the result is picture size was changed only but i mean 512px is picture should have more quality than 256px(more zoom level) and i'm not understand the whole code in that.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I needed the same thing and found a solution. I modified the gdal2tiles.py file (as suggested by user30184). After changing all of the "256" values in the code to "512", I found that the modified gdal2tiles script did create the tiles in 512x512 resolution. I also tested this using MapBox and confirmed that the higher resolution tiles do display properly.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of gdal2tiles (since 3.1.0) have a `--tilesize=PIXELS` option.